# There seems to be only one question on this site

Tags: support

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions

I only see one question on this page, is that correct?

Comment: A screenshot might help assess the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you by chance in the **Featured** tab?

[image]

That has only one question in it, because it lists only the questions with bounties. When you pick one of these questions filters, Stack Exchange remembers it for a while. (The *Active* filter is how the front page is sorted.)

Comment: Yes, sorry that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

That's not right.

You are having a technical problem.

Providing more information might help us help you.